# Sustituir ciertos datos de columnas por otros

Tags: python, dataframe, replace

estoy teniendo problemas con una sustitución de datos en varias columnas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Os paso una imagen del DataFrame que tengo, se ve que hay varias columnas que están en blanco.
Concretamente tienen esta forma " ".
Estoy usando replace para esto, con el siguiente código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto debería de reemplazarme solo el número limitado que pongo (en este caso 5), pero no es así.
Me reemplaza todos los espacios en blanco, como podéis ver en esta imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado con varias alternativas del comando replace, pero no hay manera.

¿Alguna sugerencia de dónde tengo el error?
Muchas gracias

Comment: Buen día, solo para ver si entendí bien, ¿Deseas limitar el número de celdas a reemplazar a 5 (O cualquier otro número)?

Comment: ¿verificaste que la imagen que subiste se vea para quienes quieres transmitirle tu pregunta?

Comment: @AgileSoul yo creo que se ve claro, se ven que hay espacios vacíos, la orden que he puesto es una de las varias opciones que estuve probando ayer. Si opinas que debo de añadir algo más a la imagen, lo miro.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato, la idea es, efectivamente, sustituir por un número determinado de datos que puedo obtener de otro Dataframe con una estructura inicial similar a este.

Comment: Si las imagenes estan bien entonces quizas es mi navegador, pues me aparece algo como 'introducir la descripcion de la imagen aqui' en lugar de las imagenes.

Comment: He puesto una respuesta, como nota adicional a lo que comentó @AgileSoul, es importante siempre agregar la información como texto para que podamos copiar y pegar y limitar el uso de imágenes a los casos donde sea absolutamente necesario. Te recomiendo leer las secciones [ask] y [tour] para familiarizarte como trabajar con el sitio y de paso obtener tu primer medalla. Saludos!

Comment: Intentaré la próxima vez meter el código y el DataFrame en texto. Muchas gracias por todo @HeytalePazguato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

La razón pora la que no funciona con [`pandas.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) es porque `n` es para indicar el número de caracteres a reemplazar en un mismo `string` es decir en cada "celda".

Como no pusiste tus datos cree un `dataframe` genérico (En el archivo "sample.csv") y tendrás que adaptar el código a tu `dataset`.

```
    colA    colB
0   a   
1   b   
2   c       algo
3   d   
4   f   
5   g       algo
6   h   
7   i   
8   j       algo
9   k
```

**Nota:** Las celdas que parecen vacías tienen en realidad un espacio en blanco  ( ) como en tu `dataset`.

Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) en combinación con [`pandas.DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).

Por defecto `mask` reemplaza todas las coincidencias con `NaN`, podrías utilizar otra cosa pero para este caso específico es mejor dejar que reemplace con `NaN`.

```
df['colB'] = df['colB'].mask(df['colB'] == ' ')
```

Al imprimir `df['colB']` obtenemos lo siguiente:

```
0     NaN
1     NaN
2    algo
3     NaN
4     NaN
5    algo
6     NaN
7     NaN
8    algo
9     NaN
Name: colB, dtype: object
```

Luego utilizamos `fillna` para rellenar los `NaN` con cualquier cosa y utilizamos el argumento `limit` para indicar el número de celdas que se van a rellenar:

```
df['colB'] = df['colB'].mask(df['colB'] == ' ').fillna('otro', limit=5)
```

Al imprimir `df['colB']` obtenemos:

```
0    otro
1    otro
2    algo
3    otro
4    otro
5    algo
6    otro
7     NaN
8    algo
9     NaN
Name: colB, dtype: object
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
df['colB'] = df['colB'].mask(df['colB'] == ' ').fillna('otro', limit=5)
print(df)
```

Esto nos devuelve el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
    colA    colB
0   a       otro
1   b       otro
2   c       algo
3   d       otro
4   f       otro
5   g       algo
6   h       otro
7   i       NaN
8   j       algo
9   k       NaN
```

Si quisieras quitar los `NaN` y volver a poner el espacio en blanco podrías hacer un `fillna` extra para rellenar con espacio en blanco todos los `NaN` de la columna, en lo personal yo creo que tener `NaN` es mejor ya que creo que representa mejor si la celda tiene valores útiles o no.

Comment: Jo! Muchas gracias! Lo que me comentas del replace era lo que me suponía y no conocía el comando mask. Funciona perfecto!

Comment: @Engel75, si la respuesta te fue útil por favor acéptala, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.